# Flutter and firebase [The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'Database Event'. firebase_database-9.0.3]

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

```
Future<List<PopularItemModel>> getMostPopular() async {
  var list = List<PopularItemModel>.empty(growable: true);
  var source =
      await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('a').child('b').child(MOST_POPULAR_REF).once();
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = source.value; // <- problem is here with 'value'
  values.forEach((key, value) {
    list.add(PopularItemModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value))));
  });

return list;
}
```

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKHCf.png)

'I just upgraded my packages and I got this problem'

Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'Database Event'. firebase_database-9.0.3

('value') must be replaced but I can't find anything to replace it with

In the end, It forced me to degrade the dependency to " firebase_database: 8.0.0 " and the problem with the last version " firebase_database: 9.0.3 "

and the code is working like superman now after degrading the package to (8.0.0).. so what should I do now If I want to upgrade the package to (9.0.3) or the latest

['value' that in version (8.0.0) img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7vOJ.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Well, I did it.. Now do you have any solution to my problem

Comment: I found the solution thanks to god
->
Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = source.snapshot.value as Map;

Answer (score 2):

Change `source.value` to `source.snapshot.value`.